# React Native: Navigation with gap or empty object?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, navigation

I'm wondering whether it's possible in React Native to have a gap in a navigation container.

So, I want to have 4 buttons but with the same layout as 5 buttons and a gap in the place of the middle button.

```
 | #1 | #2 | GAP | #3 | #4 |
```

Not sure if that's possible or if I can fake a button without a link?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Using Bottom Tabs Navigator with Tab.Screen for each button.

Comment: put more code if you can! that is not presenting a minimal reproducible issue. Which is the library that you are using for the navigation? is that component a TabView? of course you could have one of your buttons with no actions. just put the button and the text, without the link and without the action in the onPress. Or even that gap is something that you need as an space in the view! just set the right css styles to handle the layout.

Comment: Hi @guiwme5 thanks for your answer. I apologise for being vague. I'm using a Bottom Tabs Navigator and I'm using "Tab.Screen" for all my buttons. From what I understand of your answer, do you mean I should use a Touchable Opacity instead of the Tab.Screen?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I've solved it! I'm not sure if it's the best solution but it has worked.

In case anyone else runs into this hurdle and also wants a single very custom button or, like in my case, wants to introduce a gap in the Bottom Bar Navigation, here's what I found.

There is an option in Bottom Tabs Navigation called, **tabBarButton** which lets you pass in a React element as that particular tab button.

So, first I created my element:

```
const CustomGap = () => (
   <View style={{width: 1}}></View>
);
```

Note 1: I passed in a width of 1 because when a View has no components within it, React won't render it. At least, that's what I noticed.

Note 2: I didn't pass in any parameters because I wanted a gap in the navigation. Otherwise, I would have passed in children and onPress.

Now, in the navigator, I go to the location I want to use as a gap and pass in my gap element as the tabBarButton

```
<Tab.Navigator>
   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={NotificationsScreen} />

   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DummyScreen}
      options={{
         tabBarButton: () => (
            <CustomGap />
         )
      }}
   />

   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={SettingsScreen} />
   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={ProfileScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I haven't passed any options for the other buttons in the example above just so you focused on the main solution. In the actual application, of course you'd be passing in options like the icon used, etc.